# How can a sinusoid be a steady current?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, maxwell-equations

As far as I understand it, a steady/stationary/constant current is defined to have $dJ/dt=0$ (i.e., no explicit time dependence). So I would say that sinusoids cannot produce steady currents, yet google tells me that there are such things as sinusoidal steady currents. How is that possible given that such sinusoidal currents have an explicit time dependence ($sin(\omega t$))?

When I imagine a steady current, the easiest picture is of a line current that has one $J=$constant (no time dependence), which produces a constant magnetic field loop at some radius away from the line/wire. How can a time-varying sinusoid also produce a constant magnetic field? Are 'steady sinusoidal currents' instead referring to a *spatially-varying sinusoid* (like a constant current density, but going around in a circular loop, i.e., a magnetic dipole)?

Comment: They never say 'steady current'. They say 'sinusoidal steady state', which means the long-time behavior of the solution to a differential equation with $V(t)$ sinusoidal.

Comment: As in, you can hook your circuit up to an AC source and it'll do something weird just after you turn it on. But if you wait a while, it'll settle down and everything in your circuit will have simple time dependence. That's the 'sinusoidal steady state'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could say that the AC current is steady if its RMS (Root Mean Square) value is steady. So in a statistical sense it's steady. It's most likely a matter of semantics than definition. Or a *different* definition for the particular application.